# Div id conflict in ClistView yii 1

Tags: yii, clistview

I am working on a Yii project,on the index page i have multiple div id's loaded by the yii the first id is named yw0 and second is yw1 and third is yw2,but after the yw1 id i have a ajax page which also generates two id's yw0 and yw1. so the new id's are conflicting with the old one what will will be the possible solution to get rid of this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dp,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'id'=>'id-of-list-view-div',
    'pager'=>array(
        'id'=>'id-of-pager-ul'
    )
));
```

You can set your own html ID on both widgets (CListView and CPager)
This way when they are reloaded they will keep the IDs and there will be no conflict

Hope it helps